# Adding Solspace Tag in Channel Form without need to hit return

Tags: solspace, safecracker

I'm using Solspace tag as a 'subject' field in conjunction with EE's native Channel Form. We have set the field to required using the rules parameter...

```
rules:FieldYear="required"
```

If the user doesn't hit enter when inputting a subject tag (or select an existing tag from the list), i.e. it doesn't get added as a tag and just sits in the field as text - the form will not submit. It's basically not counting it as a valid field, as technically there is no tag selected.

Is there any simple way to just convert that text to a tag on submission? Would be really helpful!

Thanks!

*(p.s. The reason why we're using the rules parameter is it gives a lot more flexibility, as you can make a field required in a specific form rather than globally across the site)*

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, that is currently not available. If you're using the [**Tag Widget**](http://www.solspace.com/docs/tag/using_with_channel_form/), you must press [Enter] between each tag. I recommend submitting this as a Feature Request under the specific add-on category. It'll also give other users the option to vote up the feature request, and help us prioritize features to add in upcoming versions of this add-on.
http://support.solspace.com/support/discussions

Alternatively, instead of the Tag widget field you could simply have a textarea field with `name="my_tag_field_name"`, and make sure each tag is on a separate line. That's essentially what the Tag widget does in the background, but in this case having a single tag in the field would submit that value with the form, and not trigger your required... requirement :)

Another idea could be to trigger some javascript before form submission, where fields with `name="my_tag_field_name"` are checked for any content. If the field is empty, fill the field with *something* then continue with the form submission.

Yet another idea would be to develop an extension which adds a value in the array of data being submitted to EE if the tag field is empty. This would have to happen before the Channel Form's validation kicks in.

Comment: No problem! Feel free to mark this answer as the main answer. :)